# Where to get a copy of mime.types file?

Tags: download, mime, file-type

Wondering if anyone experienced develop anything that deals with mime type and know where to get a copy of latest mime.types. A file that contains all the MIME Type/Extention.

ftp dir at [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) seem to be no longer accessible.

I have a java program which requires file that lists all mime types and extentions for file type validation.

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mmp = new MimetypesFileTypeMap("path/to/mime.types");
```

example of mime.types content

```
# MIME type         Extension
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.ttc
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.wem
application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml
application/vnd.ms-artgalry
application/vnd.ms-asf
application/vnd.ms-excel    xls
application/vnd.ms-lrm
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint   ppt
```

Update:

Found an efficient [copy of this file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup) in Apache HTTPD repos

Comment: The link you posted works fine. IANA is the authoritative source; getting the information from anywhere else seems misdirected. But don't expect it to cover every file type known to man; it contains the official IANA types.

Comment: Yes, that's right but like I mentioned, I'd like to get a copy of a "deployable" file not only information. In fact I've found it in apache HTTPD repos directory. Although it's not official but efficient enough.  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup

Comment: I got it from nginx: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nginx/nginx/master/conf/mime.types

Answer (score 1):

The latest always is in the trunk of this repository
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup